# Load the array from array list in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

Here I load array from data table to array list.

```
public static ArrayList LoadView()  

    {  
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    DataView view = new DataView(dt);  
    view.RowFilter = (("Name='AD'"));  
    DataTable dtcopy = view.ToTable("Selected", false, "Row1", "Row2");  
    var arr = dtcopy.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.ItemArray).ToArray();  
    ItemList.Add(arr1);  

    DataView view2 = new DataView(dt);  
    view2.RowFilter = (("Name='ProE'"));  
    DataTable dtcopy2 = view2.ToTable("Selected", false, "Row1", "Row2");  
    // remove some column from datatable  
    var arr2 = dtcopy2.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(r => r.ItemArray).ToArray();//Convert datatable to array    
    ItemList.Add(arr2);  

    return Itemlist;   
    }
```

Itemlist Contain array arr1,array arr2.Now I seperate the array from array list.

```
Javascript:  
PageMethods.LoadView();  
function LoadSucc(obj)//Returned arraylist  
{  
var goog1 = [];  
goog1 = arr1;  

var goog2 = [];  
goog2 = arr2;  
 }
```

But I can't get the solution.Suggest Some Ideas to solve my Issue.Answer rather than comments are Appreciated.

Comment: where is this method `LoadAssetAssignView` defined?

Comment: In your `LoadSucc` function, what **is** `obj`? Your comment says "Returned arraylist", but you can't have a C# object in JavaScript. How is the C# `ArrayList` ending up in a JS object?

Comment: Sorry ,Actually its a loadview @RBT

Comment: If i return a single array then it will sit in the obj and loaded in goog.But don't know how to seperate the array from arraylist .